# public packages / classes which should not be part of the public API

Tags: java, api, maven

I have public packages/classes which should not be part of the public API. However I guess I can't make a new API-maven bundle because the core-project also uses the public API.

It should be a common case, but I think that's a Java problem of not allowing fine grained access.

Do you have any hints of how to "protect" from accessing public classes which should not be part of the public API? However it really seems to be a common case most developers haven't thought about or at least haven't done anything to protect these classes from being accessed from the outside.

Comment: I don't follow.  Do you control these classes?  Why can't you just make them not public?

Comment: Yes, but I'm using them from other packages in my project for instance org.sirix.axis, org.sirix.axis.filter, org.sirix.access, org.sirix.node, org.sirix.api (for the public api) and other packages/classes. in org.sirix.access.NodeReadTrxImpl which implements org.sirix.api.NodeReadTrx I'm also using the nodes from package org.sirix.node. Or did I miss something? At least it shouldn't be possible to provide an access modifier other than public in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the classes that are should not be accessed are put into another package named "internal". So you would have **com.company.application** for the api classes, and **com.company.application.internal** for the implementation classes. But there is no enforcement of this.  In the OSGI model, there is more fine-grained control over what packages are exported from a bundle, but not in plain Java.